# Accuracy of K Nearest Neighbor in near-ties

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Suppose you have a case where there's a near-tie in K Nearest Neighbor Algorithm - 3 of the K Nearest Neighbors are in class `A` and 2 of the K Nearest Neighbors are in class `B`. (Obviously, `K = 5`). Effectively, that means that a single document is determining which class your item should be in. In this case, would `K = 5` actually be significantly better than `K = 1`? Would it be *any* better at all? Or am I missing something?

Suppose, for example, that there's actually a 50% chance that something will fall into class `A` and a 50% chance of it falling into class `B`, and that the documents are essentially "spread" randomly. This is a rather contrived example, but under this situation at least it seems that K = 5 is no better than k = 1 (in each case, there's a 50 - 50 chance of it being in one class vs. another). For cases like that, do we just say "that kind of a distribution is unlikely to happen in 'real life,' and K Nearest Neighbor is just a probabilistic algorithm anyway"?

Put another way, can K Nearest Neighbor appear to find patterns that don't exist in random (or close to random) data, or in data that's fairly "uniformly" distributed? (I suppose that, for a large number of classifications, it probably *wouldn't* show any pattern, but for a small number of classifications it might appear to show a nonexistent pattern).

Comment: Define "find patterns". On random data, the predicted class will look random, so what?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse That's my point, though - it may *look* like it's finding patterns when there aren't any. Just because the data is random overall doesn't mean that it won't *look* like there are patterns locally.

Comment: The thing is, I wouldn't call it a pattern. kNN doesn't have a notion of "pattern".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that KNN, when run on bogus data, can appear to find patterns which don't exist. However, you could say the same for soft-margin SVM, or logistic regression, or nearly any classification algorithm.

Therefore it's necessary to perform cross-validation on classification models to ensure that the model is not overfitting to random noise.

About your example with $k = 5$. I think the better way to look a it, is instead of the classification of your datapoint being determined with just a single vote, it's now determined by 5 votes, which on average, may reflect reality better than just one vote (this depends heavily on the dataset though).

Suppose 999 students elected a class president, and the final vote came down to 500 vs 499. Sure, it all came down to the last person to vote, but that doesn't mean the vote couldn't have just been replaced by one random student voting.

Comment: Would that imply that the probability of the last person voting for one of the candidates isn't necessarily 50 - 50 (i.e. that it's not necessarily like picking a candidate for Class President at full random)? I suppose the fact that? I suppose that you *could* argue that the fact that 500 students voted in favor of the guy who won implies that there's a slightly higher probability of someone voting for that candidate than the guy who lost (although it seems vaguely circular to me).

Comment: Well for classifying random noise, whatever $k$ is, you're not going to get good results out of it, and you are correct that it is completely random whatever $k$ is. But the idea is that when there are actually patterns in the data, then a larger $k$ can reduce the effect of randomness in your classification (at the cost of a larger bias, see bias-variance tradeoff)

Comment: So, unless the data actually *is* truly random, the odds are you're still picking up on a real pattern (even if it *was* a near-tie in that case)?

Comment: This is very difficult to say in general. Even if the data is not completely random, most data has some degree of randomness to it, so you can still pick up a "fake" pattern. In general, larger $k$ reduces the effect of this randomness. On the other hand, smaller $k$ can be more sensitive to patterns which will be smoothed out by larger $k$. Selection of $k$ is a nontrivial task, but you should try something like cross-validation to help you choose.